# Major SEO Pitfalls of JavaScript loaded CSS?

Tags: seo, css, javascript

Looking to start with a basic.css and have JavaScript load enhanced.css when JavaScript is ebabled. What major negatives will this have for Search Engines indexing and ranking my site?

Comment: basic.css has CSS resets and almost nothing else (no major layout styles). Enhance.css has responsive design CSS styles e.g. 320, 480, 768, 1024, etc layouts...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

err - none.

Search Engines don't really care about your presentation - just your content (and links).

The only time this could become a factor is if you are using either JS or CSS or a combination of both to deliberately hide content (in the spammy sense, not in the AJAX toggle sense), or to try and hide a sneaky redirect.

You could start to concern yourself with absolute positioning and *it's* impacts, but even at that level of granularity, you'd be worrying about nothing in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 0):

It's the actual content that matters to search engines - the presence or lack of a stylesheet shouldn't make any real difference. A possible exception being if JavaScript is used to make significant changes to the markup, which the SEs would not pick up on. That aside, I can't see what difference it makes.